# Ajax Requests in Firefox 5, works in Webkit

Tags: ajax, json, firefox, xmlhttprequest

Here is the first simple javascript ajax request that I tried that did not work.

```
var obj = {};
obj.action = "clubbar";
$.post("/ajax/lojack", obj, function(data){ 
var real = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

When I do the json parse function i get this error

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Not enough arguments" nsresult: "0x80570001 (NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS)" location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:8888//admin/newclubbar.jsp :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 381" data: no]
```

When I tried to do it without jquery, I get the same error:

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/ajax/lojack?action=clubbar",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/html");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(null); I also tried xml.http.send("");
```

I could post the actual JSON but Webkit has no problem with it

Comment: Thanks for editing for some reason this comment didn't hit my in box.  Its a j2ee app so after I remove all the Java includes and leave the page with just html/css/javascript the exception changes from line 381 to 370.  This is line 368 - 372:

Comment: `var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.setAttribute('href', '');
  a.setAttribute('going_' + nbhood.id);
  a.setAttribute('data-role', 'button');`
  a.innerHTML = "Going";

Comment: Sincerest apologies..... `a.setAttribute('going_' + nbhood.id);` You were right about the line number setAttribute has two parameters...duhhhhhhh. I was tired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sincerest apologies..... a.setAttribute('going_' + nbhood.id); You were right about the line number setAttribute has two parameters...duhhhhhhh. I was tired.